# Filter brightness transition CSS3

Tags: html, css, filter, transition, brightness

i'm working on transitions and filters on images.
i have this code in my page:

```css
.circle {
  z-index: 99;
  transition: 1s ease;
  filter: brightness(1)
}

.circle:hover {
  filter: brightness(3)
}
```

```html
<div class="animation">
  <img class="centeredLayer1 vape" src="export-psd/Layer-0.png" alt="">
  <img class="centeredLayer1 circle" src="export-psd/CIRCLE-OFF.png" alt="">
</div>
```

When i mantain the hover on the div. The image starts the brighness animation correctly but when the transition time is over the images turn on the initial status. This bheavior seems happens only with the brightness. I tried with blur and other filters and seems work correctly.

i'm doing something wrong? i tried wit the webkit prefix already but i got same results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can add simple jQuery or javascript to achieve this.

Comment: yeah but i wanna know why the brightness after the transition turn back on the initial status

Comment: `:hover` selector is used to select elements only when you mouse over them. Once you mouse out, it will back to their original sate.